# Ember.js Grouping Results

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to achieve a "group by" functionality in Ember.js and its proving more difficult than I originally thought.

```
[{date: '2014-01-15T16:22:16-08:00', message: 'Tidal wave occurred'},
{date: '2014-01-15T05:00:16-08:00', message: 'Tornado destroyed town'},
{date: '2014-01-13T14:22:16-08:00', message: 'Volcanic eruption, likely'},
{date: '2014-01-13T16:24:16-08:00', message: 'Ice shelf calving off completely'},
{date: '2014-01-11T11:27:26-08:00', message: 'Mother-in-law visiting'}]
```

I'm looking for final output similar to this:

```
Today
----------
4:22 pm - Tidal wave occurred
5:00 am - Tornado destroyed town

Monday
----------
2:22 pm - Volcanic eruption, likely
...etc., etc.
```

Right now this data is bound to an ArrayController. Each object has a computed property to get "year/month/day" for the grouping comparison.

```
var ActivityController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

    groupedResults: function () {
        var result = [];

        //Iterate over each item in the list, but do what with it?
        this.get('content').filter(function (item) {

        });

        return result;
    }.property('content.[]')

});
```

Any tips on the best way to implement this? Ember ships with filterBy and mapBy, but no groupBy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a Groupable implementation I've adapted a bit:

```
Groupable = Ember.Mixin.create
  group: null
  ungroupedContent: null

  groupedContent: (->
    model = @
    groupedContent = Ember.A([])

    groupCallback = @get('group')
    ungroupedContent = @get('ungroupedContent')

    return groupedContent unless groupCallback
    return groupedContent unless ungroupedContent

    ungroupedContent.forEach (item) ->
      group = groupCallback.call(model, item)
      return unless groupKey = group.get('key')

      foundGroup = groupedContent.findProperty('group.key', groupKey)

      unless foundGroup
        foundGroup = groupedContent.pushObject Ember.ArrayProxy.create
          group: group,
          content: Ember.A([])

      foundGroup.get('content').pushObject(item)

    groupedContent
  ).property('group', 'ungroupedContent.@each')
```

Controller usage:

```
ActivitiesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend Groupable,
  ungroupedContentBinding: 'content' # tell Groupable where your default content is

  # the callback that will be called for every
  # item in your content array -
  # just return the same 'key' to put it in the same group
  group: (activity) ->
    Ember.Object.create
      key: moment.utc(activity.get('date')).format('YYYY-MM-DD') # using momentjs to pluck the day from the date
      description: 'some string describing this group (if you want)'
```

Template usage:

```
{{#each groupedContent}}
  {{group.key}} - {{group.description}}

  {{#each content}}
    Here's the really bad thing that happened: {{message}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Essentially, all that the Groupable mixin does is loop through your normal content ArrayProxy and calls a function to determine what group it belongs to. If that group object doesn't already exist (i.e. no matching `group.key` was found), it creates it before adding the current content item to the *group's* content.

So what you end up with in your template is a new array (`ArrayProxy`) of objects (`Ember.Object`), with each object having a `group` property (which must have at least a `key` property to identify it) and a `content` property (which contains the content belonging to that group).

Comment: Code looks great - getting an error though: ```foundGroup = groupedContent.findProperty('group.key', groupKey)``` groupedContent has no method 'findProperty'. Not sure why though, since groupedContent is returning an Ember object...

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Does inputting `Ember.A([]).findProperty` in your console return anything?

Comment: It does - but the group() function on the ActivitiesController is returning an object, not an enumerable. Which is why there is no findProperty. Should I use something else?

Comment: `findProperty` is being called on `groupedContent`, which should just be an array. It's all working as expected for me in my project - can you post your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry - your code is working perfectly. I made a typo and assigned the wrong thing to groupedContent. Thanks!!

Comment: Please avoid answers in coffeescript, can you use plain javascript instead?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation, made available on `Array` objects:

```
var groupByMethod = Ember.Mixin.create({
  groupBy: function(key) {        
    var result = [];
    var object, value;

    this.forEach(function(item) {
      value = item.get ? item.get(key) : item[key];
      object = result.findProperty('value', value);
      if (!object) {
        object = {
          value: value,
          items: []
        };
        result.push(object);
      }
      return object.items.push(item);
    });

    return result.getEach('items');
  }
});

groupByMethod.apply(Array.prototype);
```

### Usage:

```
> var posts = [{id: 1, author: 'John'}, {id:2, author: 'Paul'}, {id:4, author: 'Paul'}, {id:5, authour: 'Tom'}];

> posts.groupBy('author')
```

[image: usage example]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Ember.computed.groupBy` like this:

```
((Ember) ->
  # Example:
  #
  #   productsByCategory: Em.computed.groupBy 'products', 'category'
  #
  #   each view.productsByCategory
  #     category.name
  #     each content
  #       content.name
  #
  Ember.computed.groupBy = (collection, groupBy) ->
    dependentKey = "#{collection}.@each.#{groupBy}"

    Ember.computed dependentKey, ->
      result = []
      @get(collection).forEach (item) ->
        unless result.findBy groupBy, item.get(groupBy)
          data = content: []
          data[groupBy] = item.get(groupBy)
          result.pushObject Ember.Object.create(data)
        result.findBy(groupBy, item.get(groupBy)).get('content').pushObject item
      result
) Ember
```